# Gekko Solver does not satisfy Constraints gives wrong solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I was using **Gekko** solver for optimizing function, but it gives wrong solution even in simple problems where it also not satisfying the given constraints.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

a = m.Var(value=0, integer=True)
b = m.Var(value=0, integer=True)

# constraints
m.Equation([a + b > 7, a**2 + b**2 < 40])
# Objective function
m.Maximize(a**3 + b**3)


m.solve(disp=False)
print(a.value[0])
print(b.value[0])
max_value = a.value[0]**3 + b.value[0]**3
print(max_value)
```

Output:

```py
2.0
6.0
224.0
```

Comment: Considering how lazy I am, can you provide the expected output?

Comment: the expected output should be no solution.

Comment: I suspect > and < in constraints really means >= and <=. (strict inequalities are somewhat meaningless in continuous relaxations). This would make things feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a check at the end reveals that Gekko finds a correct solution within the requested tolerance although the default solver is IPOPT that finds a continuous solution even when `integer=True` is requested.

```
a = a.value[0]; b = b.value[0]
print('a+b>7',a+b)
print('a^2+b^2<40',a**2+b**2)

# 0.71611780666
# 6.2838821838
# 248.50000026418317
# a+b>7 6.99999999046
# a^2+b^2<40 40.00000001289459
```

Try switching to the MINLP solver APOPT with `m.options.SOLVER=1`. Inequalities `<` and `<=` are equivalent in Gekko because it is a numerical solution.

```
2.0
6.0
224.0
a+b>7 8.0
a^2+b^2<40 40.0
```

If it is `<` or `>` in the mathematical sense that 7 and 40 are not allowable then shift up or down one integer on the constraints such as to `>=8` and `<=39`.

```py
m.Equation([a + b >= 8, \
            a**2 + b**2 <= 39])
```

Results are correct:

```
a=3.0  b=5.0  Objective: 152.0
a+b>=8 with a+b=8.0 (constraint satisfied)
a^2+b^2=<39 with a^2+b^2=34.0 (constraint satisfied)
```

Is there something else missing here? Why is there a claim of no feasible solution?

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

a = m.Var(value=0, integer=True)
b = m.Var(value=0, integer=True)

# constraints
m.Equation([a + b >= 7, \
            a**2 + b**2 <= 40])
# Objective function
m.Maximize(a**3 + b**3)

m.options.SOLVER =1
m.solve(disp=True)
print(a.value[0])
print(b.value[0])
max_value = a.value[0]**3 + b.value[0]**3
print(max_value)

a = a.value[0]; b = b.value[0]
print('a+b>7',a+b)
print('a^2+b^2<40',a**2+b**2)
```